Error in Mern stack while registering in website
loading(pin):true
isAuthenticated(pin):false
user(pin):null
error(pin):null
the above detail is in the state and the state got stuck in REGISTER_USER_REQUEST , it is not going for the other state
How to resolve it , I'm using cloudinary for storing images which will be taken by users  and the link will get stored in the backend

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
